# Type Error:PollingEngineExceptions() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given) in python

Tags: python

My endpoint is defined as

```
@app.route('/PollingEngineExceptions',methods=['POST'])
def PollingEngineExceptions(PollingException): 
..
return response
```

Im posting to this endpoint

```
def test_atg_polling_exception(self):
        jsonEncoder = CustomJSONEncoder()      
        a= PollingException('System.OutOfMemoryException','System.OutOfMemoryException','System.OutOfMemoryException','2009-02-15T00:00:00Z')
        jsonmsg=jsonEncoder.default(a)
        response = requests.post("http://localhost:5000/PollingEngineExceptions",data=jsonmsg)
```

when I POSTing im getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: PollingEngineExceptions() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

What Im doing wrong here?

Comment: Why does `test_atg_polling_exception` take an argument (self)? It doesn't seem to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed like correcting my endpoint;

```
@app.route('/ATGPollingEngineExceptions',methods=['POST'])
def ATGPollingEngineExceptions(): 
    value = request.values
    print value
    ...
    return response
```